# iterating through a linked list inserting STL vector values

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to iterate over a vector and get the data into the linked list nodes... I know I can use the STL iterator for vector, but what can I use to loop over the linked list? I don't think I can use STL list iterator, right?

*List.h*

```c
class List {
public:
    List();
    void addNode(int addData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void printList();

private:
    typedef struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
};
```

*List.cpp*

```c
List::List() {
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::addNode(int addData){
    nodePtr n = new Node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}

void List::deleteNode(int delData) {
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL && curr->data != delData) {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr == NULL) {
        cout << delData << " was not in the list.\n";
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else {
        delPtr = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        temp->next = curr;
        if(delPtr == head) {
            head = head->next;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        delete delPtr;
    }
}

void List::printList() {
    curr = head;
    while(curr !=NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr= curr->next;
    }
}
```

*main.cpp*

```c
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Enter some integers, space delimited:\n";
    string someString;
    getline(cin, someString);

    istringstream stringStream( someString );
    vector<int> integers;
    int n;
    while (stringStream >> n)
        List listOfInts;
    listOfInts.addNode(/* stuff in here*/)
    integers.push_back(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `std::list`?

Comment: you would think id use that... unfortunately, im a student, and we are supposed to use the defined class... is it even possible? of all the linked list tutorials ive watched, none of them mention anything about looping through the list.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode The way that List class has been written does not include any way to iterate through the linked list. So it's a pretty rubbish class (but probably it's just meant for teaching purposes). **But** given the task you have to do I don't see why you need to iterate through the linked list, its the vector you need to iterate through. Then all you do is call `addNode` on the list.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode Sorry no offense meant by the above comment, when I wrote it was assuming that you'd been given that List class, but now I'm thinking that you probably wrote it yourself. A well rounded linked list class would have methods to iterate though, but no doubt you're just writing the code that you've been told to write.

Comment: That list class is an abomination. Don't ever refer to it as something you can use to learn how to construct a class. For example, "curr" should be a local variable to the the addNode and deleteNode functions. It should be declared in those functions and not as part of the class. And that is just one of the several horrible things found in that class. Use it for the assignment but never refer back to it for the rest of your life. Unless you want a good laugh a decade from now.

Comment: @john, no worries, i am still learning. if the code was amazing, i wouldn't be posting here. what would that look an iterator method look like? thats kind of what im after.... in class we were given STL iterators for the containers, but not really any way to write our own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through the linked list. Use `addNode` to add items to the linked list.

```
vector<int> vec;
...
List list;
for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end() ++i)
    list.addNode(*i);
```

That's all there is to it.